# The inode, owner, group all became question marks, is there any way to delete such file?

Tags: linux

The image is from command `ls -il`:

[image: The image is from command ls -il]

When I use `rm -f`, it shows this error message:

> `rm: cannot remove '/data0/workspace/dataset/imagenet21k_resized/imagenet21k_train/n07818689/n07818689_3980.JPEG': Bad message`

Is there any way to delete files like these?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a corrupted file system.

Can you umount to take it offline (or USB boot the machine) and then use fsck to check and fix the filesystem.

If it isn't too messed up, you might then be able to delete the file.
Might also be a sign of hardware failure. So start keeping good backups.